# save downloaded image and use it in google maps as marker android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps

1) I'd like to download a image whose URL has been provided, save it to the SD card/internal memory. (lower quality and resize to say 100x100px)
2) use the downloaded image as a google maps marker

I have done the download image part but i need to resize it, and then somehow retrieve it in another activity as a google maps marker. any help on this?

this is the code i have so far for downloading (permissions are granted, code mostly taken form various sources):

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return Download(urls[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap picture) {
        try {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            // the File to save
            File file = new File(path, "picture.jpg");
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG with 85% compression rate
            picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
            fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream

            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),
                    file.getName(),file.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Download", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
1)

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    return Download(urls[0]);
}

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap picture) {
        try {
            picture = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(picture, 100, 100, true);
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            // the File to save
            File file = new File(path, "picture.jpg");
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG with 85% compression rate
            picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
            fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Download", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

2)

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File file = new File(path, "picture.jpg");
Bitmap slikaweb = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(file));
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
try {
    pictureweb = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file),
               null, options);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(poz).title("")
         .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(pictureweb)));
```